# Tkinter - Frame Scrolling into Another Frame?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm having an issue where I have two frames on a grid; one is on top, and one is on bottom. Both have a canvas in the frame. In the bottom canvas, I have a scrollbar. The only issue is that when I scroll down, the contents of that canvas (and thus frame) scroll into the top frame, which obviously is less than ideal.

I've tried to limit the width and height of each to no avail, and I'm wondering if there's something I can do to make the contents "disappear" within the frame as opposed to just leaving its own frame. Any scrolling content on the web does this, so there has to be a way.

Here's my code; "test" is the top canvas, and "testCanvas" is the bottom canvas created in the bottom frame. As you can see, "testCanvas" scrolls into "test". I've tried perusing tutorialspoint, effbot, and stackoverflow, but I can't quite figure it out.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from struct import *
import array
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

frame = Frame()
frame.pack()

root.minsize(width=230, height=70)
root.maxsize(width=1070, height=500)

IDlabel = ttk.Label(frame, text="Enter ID:")
IDlabel.pack()

IDentry = ttk.Entry(frame)
IDentry.pack()

def close():
    root.quit()

def submit(event):

    userIDentry = IDentry.get()

    if userIDentry == '':
        exit()

    headerFrame = Frame(root, width=5, height=5)  
    headerFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)

    channelFrame = Frame(root, width=720, height=400) 
    channelFrame.grid(row=1, column=0)
    channelFrame.pack_propagate(0)
    frame.destroy()

    additionalFrame = Frame(root)

    test = Canvas(headerFrame)

    testCanvas = Canvas(channelFrame)

    testCanvas.create_window((3,0), window=additionalFrame, anchor=NW)

    vbar = Scrollbar(channelFrame, orient=VERTICAL)
    vbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    vbar.config(command=testCanvas.yview)

    sampleOutput = ttk.Label(test, text="Sample")
    sampleOutput.grid(row=1, column=1)

    secondFrameOutput = ttk.Label(additionalFrame, text="My scrolling behavior is off", font="Verdana 10 bold")
    secondFrameOutput.grid(row=0, column=1)

    closeButton = ttk.Button(additionalFrame, text="Close", command=close)
    closeButton.grid(row=1, column=2)

    testCanvas.config(width=2200, height=600)
    testCanvas.config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
    testCanvas.pack()

    testCanvas.config(scrollregion=(0,0,700,1145))

    test.config(width=50, height=50)
    test.pack()

root.bind('<Return>', submit)

submitButton = ttk.Button(frame, text="Submit", command=submit)
submitButton.bind('<Button-1>', submit)
submitButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You say you have two frames, but you say " "testCanvas" is the bottom frame". Are you talking about frames or canvases?

Comment: Sorry, Bryan. I got things mixed up. Let me make the necessary changes here--I meant to say that testCanvas is the canvas instantiated in the bottom frame. What else do you find confusing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all honesty, I think you need to throw all of that code out and start over. There's just too much wrong with it -- you are trying to solve an equation with too many unknown variables.

For example, you create a frame in the root window and pack it, then later you destroy it and use grid to add some other widgets. While it's possible to make that work, it makes it very hard to grasp what your code is doing. Is that part of the problem? Is it completely unrelated? How do you know?

You also create a header frame that is only 5x5 pixels - why so small? You create a canvas near the top of the code but then configure the size near the bottom of the code. You create a label and pack it in a canvas -- packing something in a canvas is possible, but I doubt that it does what you think it does.

Start with a function (or a class) that creates a single frame. Ignore the initial entry widget and button, focus on the frame. In that function add in a top and bottom frame. Stop, and make sure those both appear where they should and in the size that you want. Give them distinct background colors during development, and maybe give them a width and height, too. Get just that working, so that it's one less variable in the equation. Make sure if behaves properly when you resize your window.

Next, add only one canvas, and add the scrollbar for that canvas. Stop, and make sure that works, and make sure your frames continue to behave the way they should. The scrollbar won't scroll since there's nothing on the canvas, but that's not important just yet.

Continue like this for the rest of your widgets. Do not progress until each widget is behaving correctly.

To create a GUI you must be methodical. Don't just start trying to juggle half a dozen widgets at once. Start with one or two, get them working, add one more, and so on.

Comment: With the frame in the root window that gets destroyed, my thinking was that I wanted the user to enter in an ID, press submit, and then the same window gets populated with the new information. I suppose that it's the right idea but poor execution; is there a better way for this? As for the obvious inconsistencies, I was experimenting too much with no concrete design pattern--I now see that. Thanks for the advice thus far.